# EclipseLink INTERSECT filter out if two sets have element in common

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, hql

could anybody help?

Entity A has a field with set of enums.

Method takes a set of enums.

Task - filter out values if A.field has 1 or more elements in common with passed set of enums.
I was trying to achieve it via INTERSECT, but the result wasn't achieved.

Working solution - NOT MEMBER OF, but it could be used only for 1 parameter... possible to implement with for(), but I am sure that it isn't a good practice...

Comment: What exactly is A.field - is it an embedded list of enums, or a single enum value?  Show the mapping and maybe even the somewhat working solution.

Comment: A.field  - set of enums...

Comment: That isn't the mapping - you should show it in your question as it may have relevance, though I think the answer fits without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to compare one collection to another in JPA.

Solutions around the issue though involve subqueries, very similar what JPA will do to evaluate your MEMBER OF clause. A sub-query lets you look at individual values in a collection and compare it to the other, and use that result in your main query. Something along the lines of:

```
"Select a from A a where a.id not in (select distinct aPrime.id from A aPrime join aPrime.field field where field in :parameterList)"
```

I'm not a DBA, but if one complains this is inefficient, there many other ways of being expressed, possibly with exists:

```
"Select a from A a where exists (select aPrime from A aPrime join aPrime.field field where field in :parameterList and aPrime.id = a.id)"
```

Comment: Thank you, but IN clause couldn't be used here...
field is a set, so it will not return expected values...
As I know IN clause couldn't be used for two set/collections

Comment: Did you try it, as it should work. The JPA specification states "INNER JOIN c.orders o" is  equivalent to "IN(c.orders) o", so you can use either to get at a single element within the collection. It is only treated as a collection when used as 'c.orders' in the where clause - as you may need to use it as such. But for joining, you are asking for multiple 'A' rows to be returned, with a single 'field' in each.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as answered if it works - only you can, and it helps others not have to scan comments to find solutions.